# Push data to elements in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = array(array("a"=>1),array("a"=>2));
```

I need to push data to sub array element in $array,

End result must be as follow,

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [a] => 1 [b] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [a] => 2 [b] => 2 ) )
```

I used following ways .

1. `foreach($array as &$a){ $a['b']=2;}`
2. $result = array_map("pushdata",$array);

   ```
   function pushdata($a){
   $a['b']=2;
   }
   ```

what is the most suitable and **performance high** way **when $array  consists of more than 1000 records**  ?

Comment: You need to use a pagination, and display pnly 5-10-30 records. That's how it should be done.

Comment: @bad_boy No It is not displaying data scenario.  this is used for algorithm. so I need to push "b" element in to each element in $array.

Comment: DO some tests and find this way

Comment: go to this link -> [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) find `array_push_before` function which is posted by a user, might do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using `array_walk()` to add a new key `b` to each sub-array:

```
$array = array(array('a' => 1), array('a' => 2));
array_walk($array, function(&$item, $key) {
  $item['b'] = 2;
});
print_r($array);
/* outputs:
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
      [a] => 1
      [b] => 2
  )
  [1] => Array
  (
      [a] => 2
      [b] => 2
  )
)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for 5 items.

```
<?php

  for($i = 1 ; $i<5 ; $i++){
     $array[] = array("a"=>$i,"b"=>2);
  }

  print_r($array);

?>
```

[See online](http://ideone.com/B7BMcO)

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) , to iterate over the array and [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to push the element to each iteration.